# In a bipartite graph $(X,Y)$ where $|x|=|y|=n$ and $\delta(G) >= n/2$ there is a perfect matching

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

Suppose $G$ is a bipartite graph with bipartition $(X,Y)$ such that $|X|=|Y|=n$ and $\delta(G) >= n/2$. Prove that Hall's condition for this graph is true, meaning there is a perfect matching in this graph.

Comment: Have you tried to prove this? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: What does $\delta(G)$ mean? What is Hall's condition?